# Extract sub-text from cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

My Excel sheet consists of "Description" column which has length text.

I want to extract only relevant text like M50,P10

For example:- Design-Tractor-Model-M50.0%_countryspecific_details_P10.0%percentage

my expected output is:- M50,P10

I tried with TextBefore/After, Find and also SUBSTITUTE functions, but not able to get it correctly.

Any simple Excel function or combination of two or three functions, which I can use it?

Comment: Can you please show us what you tried? It would also be useful to see more than one piece of sample data and the expected outcome.

Comment: Use FIND & SUBSTITUTE to get the position for those "%" characters (https://exceljet.net/formulas/position-of-2nd-3rd-etc-instance-of-character). From there, you can use a combination of MID, LEFT and RIGHT functions to get the substring you need.

Comment: You have tagged Excel 2010. What happened when you tried `TEXTBEFORE`? Please edit your question to show the formulas you actually used and the errors that occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go with `FILTERXML()`. Try-

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",1,TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".0%","%_"),{"-","_"}))&"</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'%')]"),"%",""))
```

Another option could be-

```
=LET(
x,TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".0%","%_"),{"-","_"}),
y,FILTER(x,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("%",x))),
TEXTJOIN(", ",1,SUBSTITUTE(y,"%",""))
)
```

[image]